# Concatenating string containing HTML doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

basically here is a working line of code (jquery/javascript):

```
$('<label>Option ' + (i + 1) + '<span class="small">Enter text</span></label><input type="text" name="option[]"><input class="extra" type="checkbox" name="checks[]" value=' + i + '>').appendTo('#container');
```

`i` works as involved in the above code. What I want is to involve the value of `i` here:

`name="checks['+i+']"`

but it doesnt seem to like concatinating this bit. I get slightly confused with this concatinating so if someone could explain to me please I would appreciate.

Comment: What does it spit out in the HTML?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" actually mean? It must work.

Comment: well it doesnt seem to concatinate this: `name="checks['+i+']"`

Comment: I don't see any problem in it. Can you explain a bit?

Comment: Then what do you get, instead of `checks[0]`, `checks[1]`, etc.

Comment: What actually comes across in the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Do not see an issue.
To make it easier to read/debug, try

```
  var html = '<label>Option ' + (i + 1) + '<span class="small">Enter text</span></label>'+
 '<input type="text" name="option['+i+']">'+
 '<input class="extra" type="checkbox" name="checks['+i+']" value="'+i+'">'
 $(html).appendTo('#container');
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine, [here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/sTecM/).

Inspecting the `checkbox` shows this output:

```
<input class="extra" type="checkbox" name="checks[0]" value="0">
```

Try copying and pasting the line out of that jsfiddle and see if that works...

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the above code in jsfiddle but dint get any issue

```
for(i = 0 ; i < 2; i++){
var html = '<label>Option ' + (i + 1) + '<span class="small">Enter text</span></label>'+
 '<input type="text" name="option['+i+']">'+
 '<input class="extra" type="checkbox" name="checks['+i+']" value="'+i+'">';
alert(html)
   }
```

try using parseInt....also can you elaborate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your html text as array elements and they are easier to read and maintain.  Also potentially faster concatenation.

```
var htmlText = [
    '<label>Option ' + (i + 1) + '<span class="small">Enter text</span></label>',
    '<input type="text" name="option[]">',
    '<input class="extra" type="checkbox" name="checks[' + i + ']" value=' + i + '>'
    ].join("");
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/WvrDH/1/)